# Chrome Extension - make a ribbon

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is it possible for a chrome extension to create and manage the contents of a ribbon at the top of every page? By this I mean an inch or so at the top of the document beneath the Chrome chrome. The user can select the content to display and control whether the ribbon displays or not.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. see [how to write a good stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) this is quickly answered by taking the time to read the documentation, then show us a specific issue you ran into.

Comment: yes it is possible, look into javascript injection